# Why is the $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR (/run/user/$UID) directory not created after "su - user"?

Tags: xdg

Why is the $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR (/run/user/$UID) directory not created after "su - user" ? :

```bash
administrateur@localhost:~$ su - test
Password:
test@localhost:~$ systemctl --user
Failed to connect to bus: $DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS and $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not defined (consider using --machine=<user>@.host --user to connect to bus of other user)
test@localhost:~$ ls /run/user/$UID
ls: cannot access '/run/user/1004': No such file or directory
test@localhost:~$ groups
test
test@localhost:~$
logout
administrateur@localhost:~$
```

EDIT0 : Doing a `sudo loginctl enable-linger test` keeps the `/run/user/$UID` directory there but the `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` variable is still not defined :

```bash
administrateur@localhost:~$ sudo loginctl enable-linger test
administrateur@localhost:~$ sudo su - test
test@localhost:~$ ls /run/user/$UID/bus
/run/user/1004/bus
test@localhost:~$ echo $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR

test@localhost:~$ 
logout
administrateur@localhost:~$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because its existence (as well as the existence of the actual "systemd --user" process you tried to access) is tied to having at least one systemd-logind *login session,* and it is deliberately not allowed to create a new session directly from within an existing session, whether it's by `su` or other tools.

`machinectl shell test@` will spawn a shell from a service (similarly to how your regular login is spawned from the 'agetty' service), and its PAM configuration includes pam_systemd, so it will have its own session created.

Marking a user for "linger mode" using `loginctl enable-linger test` will cause systemd-logind to instead create the runtime directory (and start the user's "systemd --user" instance) on boot and keep it permanently, regardless of the session count.

Starting with systemd v239 or later, it is also possible to manually start a user's service manager through `user@<uid>.service` – the runtime directory will be automatically set up as a dependency (in earlier versions it was tied to logind's internals).

Comment: Can you please take a look at my EDIT0. The `/run/user/$UID` is now created but the `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` variable nor the `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` are defined therefore `systemctl --user` cannot be used.

Comment: They're set by the same pam_systemd that also requests a session. But because `su` isn't allowed to create sessions in normal usage (and on top of that, in the few situations where su *would* be allowed to create a session, it would be undesirable to create one), many distributions deliberately leave pam_systemd out of the PAM configuration for su and sudo. Use the `-M test@.host` option as systemctl suggests.

Comment: You mean `sudo systemctl --user -M test@.host .....` right ?

Comment: Yes, that'll achieve the same thing as manually setting XDG_RUNTIME_DIR and will control that user's "systemd --user" instance. (Note that the hostname needs to be literally `.host` to make it use local access.)